# Little help with permutations

Tags: probability

There are 4 letters $A, B, C, D$ with repetitions permitted. These letters are used in a a 3 letter code (the order is important).

- Question 1:

  How many different 3 letter codes can be made?
- Question 2:

  If one code is chosen at random from the set of all possible codes, what is the probability it contains two A's and a D?

Now I haven't done probability in a very long time but I believe this is just a standard permutation question? Would I be correct in saying that the first question is $4^3$? So there will be 64 different codes.

Comment: You're right about the number of possible codes. What did you try for second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the answer of the first question is $64$.
For the second question you get:
$${{3!\over2!}\over64}={3\over64}$$

Comment: Thanks, where did you get the $3!/2!$ from?

Comment: If there are n objects and a particular object is repeated x times then the number of permutations are n!/x!.

Comment: In general form-If object A is repeated a times,object B is repeated b times,object C is repeated c times then Permutations=n!/(a!b!c!...)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How many codes satisfying the condition that they include two A and one D are there?